# Why is my class not acceptable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is my first forray into Java, and I am trying to get my head around "Hello World" using Intellij IDEA.

It's not so much the syntax I am having trouble with, more the IDE itself.

First of all, I have downloaded and installed IntelliJ IDEA, and both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the Java JDK. IDEA has no trouble finding my Java JDK install, and providing me with intellisense. I have created a test solution named `Test`, and a `src` directory to place my source files. My solution explorer looks like this:

[image: Solution Explorer]

My Java class is below, it compiles successfully:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }


}
```

I have added the Java JDK to my environmental variables on my computer, and I am able to navigate to the compiled class, and run it in command line. It runs fine.

My issue comes whenever I try and run the class from inside IDEA, for the purposes of debugging. When I click on `Run`, it asks me to edit my Environmental variables. In the dialogue box that appears, I select `Application` under `Defaults`, and try and select `HelloWorld` as my main class. I get an error telling me that `HelloWorld` is not acceptable, as shown below:

[image: Error]

My question is, how do I run my Java console application inside IDEA for the purpose of debugging? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`main` method should be with `public` modifier

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or even better

```
public static void main( final String[] args )
```

Comment: D'oh, of course it should be public, thanks. What does the `final` keyword do, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: `final` is like a `const` in C#

Comment: I was also leaving out the `String[] args`

Comment: Leaving out static keyword will also cause Intellij to claim that the class is not acceptable.

Comment: I was getting this error because I didn't notice I was dealing with a JUnit config and it wasn't a test. Whoops

Comment: Same here @AramKocharyan. Btw `String[ ] args` and `String args[ ]` works but why `String[ ] args` is used more?

Answer (score 0):

Dare I admit it?
I overlooked `main()` parameters! 
`main(String[] args)` is of course the proper signature. 
... I am pretty sure that was in Java 101.