# Jar file from LeanFT project - Class not acceptable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, leanft

I have some `TestNG` based `LeanFT` test cases and try to generate `jar` file. I use `IntelliJ IDEA` to set artifact's details under `File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies`. I select classname, but get error, that is not acceptable.

[image]

**UPDATE 2018.05.03.**
I created main method in a new class, but got same error message.

```
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.Parser;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class LeanFTest {
    public void main() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();

        String xmlFileName = "testng.xml";
        List<XmlSuite> suite = (List<XmlSuite>)(new Parser(xmlFileName).parse());
        testNG.setXmlSuites(suite);

        testNG.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464637/why-is-my-class-not-acceptable ?

Comment: @AydinK. : I tried this already.

Comment: Please post the main class code? Also I hope the class is public as well ?

Comment: It has `@Test public void test() throws GeneralLeanFtException { }` method. It looks like as last example on this page: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_Java/codeex_Mobile.htm

Comment: java, when starting a `.jar`, uses a specific `main` signature: `public static void main(String[] args)` signature. Make sure you adapt to this signature

Comment: @Adelin : Jar is generated, but got "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again" error message, when try to execute it. It is working when I use IDE for execution and doesn't use any arguments or parameter values.

Comment: Kinda like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in-eclips

Comment: Yes, I checked this thread too, but wasn't there accepted solution/exact fix, just possible solutions.

Comment: @plaidshirt - Ok may be, but that's a different issue unrelated to LeanFT. Most probably there's an issue with the way it's all packaged and configured. If you think it's worth it, try starting from scratch, with a simple `println` program, and then gradually add LeanFT and TestNG jars and then create the structure I proposed in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some kind of combination between test project (using LeanFT TestNG template), java app, who-knows-what-else app.

If you have a `main` method and still want to trigger TestNG tests, you need to use the TestNG class. For example

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
testNG.setTestClasses(WebTestFactory.class);
testNG.run();
```

You can read more about this approach in the [official docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) or in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465695/how-to-run-testng-tests-from-main-in-an-executable-jar)

If you don't have a `main` class, you should create one. (how else could a `.jar` file know what is the entry point?).

All in all, this error indicates there's a conflict between project type and project structure (content)

---

As per your recent comment: *Could you please show me example/pattern, where to put main() method?*

1. You can create a new class file or even use `LeanFTest`
2. Create `main` method.

   Whatever you do in the main method will drive your whole app. 
   In your specific case (executing TestNG tests) you will need to do the followings, **in your main method**:
3. Create a test ng instance (`TestNG testNG = new TestNG();`)
4. Use this instance to prepare the test suite

   Pointing towards the SO thread above (again), it would mean something like:

   ```
   String xmlFileName = "testng.xml";
   List<XmlSuite> suite = (List <XmlSuite>)(new Parser(xmlFileName).parse());
   testNG.setXmlSuites(suite);
   ```
5. Run the suite

   ```
   testNG.run();
   ```

After that, when you create your artifact, you point to the class that has the main method and double clicking the `.jar` (or executing it from command line) should start the test suite.

Comment: Could you please show me example/pattern, where to put `main()` method? I used examples like this: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/SetupLeanFT.htm to design tests.

Comment: I created new class, but got same error message. I edited also question.