# Main is not acceptable in intellij

Tags: java

i just created a “Main” java class in intellij, i'm basically following tutorials of udacity but when i tried to run it the green button was disabled and then i tried to edit configuration and it said "Main is not acceptable" can someone tell me why is it happening? I have already asked this on udacity forum but no help yet.

While searching online i have found this link of stack overflow [Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464637/why-is-my-class-not-acceptable) but this didn't help me their problem and my problem is different but i did try adding *final* before `String[]` but still it is saying the same "main is not acceptable".

My code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Also check screenshot.

[image: error screenshot]

[image: main code screenshot]

Comment: You have `String` and `System` keywords highlighted red, that's the first thing to inspect. Do you have JDK installed and selected for this project?

Comment: What is listed under Files > Project Structure... > Project > Project SDK ?

Comment: yes JDK is installed and i selected it before starting this project, one thing more i used this intellij for kotlin in 2018 can that be a reason of this error?